# unable to redirect htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

Ok I tried my best and googled a lot.

Finally come up with a solution to redirect `www.mysite.com/?page=2 to www.mysite.com`. But my solution gives 404 error for rest of the page . 
Here is my solution :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?Page=2$ 
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]`
```

What I want is to redirect `www.mysite.com/?page=2 to www.mysite.com`

There can be `page=(any numeric value)`

Please guide.

Thanks !

Comment: Try to change `RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule .? http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]`

Comment: Yeah I did that but didnt worked !

Comment: Gives an error on Chrome browser That "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The question mark doesn't seem to be included in the query string variable. This code should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=[0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Woops, seems removing the question mark all together does the trick :)

Comment: Yes..wat is happening is that upon using this url www.mysite.com/?Page=2 shows the home page content. I want to redirect it to home page or delete this ?Page=2 from the URL.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted an external redirect. I've updated my answer again, this time the page parameter can also be of any numeric value and the query parameters are stripped (just the way you did it in your question, doh ;) )

Comment: This also not working/ redirecting. It should be i think..my website is on magento and I have also cleared the cache but this solution doesnt seems to be working..:-((

Comment: Hm. Does the query string *only* consist of **?page=2** or do you have other parameters? For example if you have *?page=2&theme=light* then the redirect will not work. To fix this change `^page=[0-9]+$` to `page=[0-9]+`

Comment: its only **?page=2** and nothing else

Comment: Weird it works on my box. Any possibility of telling the URL? What is the error message or what happens?

Comment: dont know how this **www.mysite.com/?Page=2** or **www.mysite.com/?Page=3 etc..** query string is generated by magento..

Comment: There is NO errro message.It shows home page so there can be duplicate copntent issue. Our SEO team dont want that URL to be seen on ..thats the requirement

Comment: Oh! It was caused by the big P in Page (in the query string). See my updated answer. Add **[NC]** (no case flag) to the `RewriteCond`. That should do it

Comment: Not working neither of these 2 **http://www.mysite.com/?page=4  http://www.mysite.com/?Page=4 ** It shows home page :( Is there any way to delete that /?Page=2 via htaccess if it is not redirecting?

Comment: Hm I'm stunned, works correctly when accessing any file like test.php?Page=2 and index.php?Page=2 but if I visit the directory without specifying the filename (like /somefolder/?Page=2) the rewrites are not firing. It might be a .htaccess / Apache issue

Comment: Ya ..am cheking to figure it out..thanks for your time and support. much much appreciated !

Comment: No problem. Would have researched more but have to do some actual work now, hehe. Hope you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

well I resolved this issue but not from htaccess. I did it via a simple PHP Coding.

Below is what I did:

`$pge=$_GET['Page'];`

`if($pge)`
`{`

```
`header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');`
```

`header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/');`

`exit();`

`}`